# SAP Hybris6.2 Database Tables Structure in Oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I have just connected the Hybris 6.2 to Oracle 11g Db. In the Sql developor i can see all the tables, however due to large number of table its been hard to find things. I found a table called CMSComponent but unable to find CMSParagraphComponent,CMSImageComponent , MiniCartComponent in it. Is it in some other table? More so if i create a new Component or any exisiting, where are they stored in database table?

Please any help is appreciated in understand the Hybris database structure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found a table called CMSComponent but unable to find
>   CMSParagraphComponent,CMSImageComponent , MiniCartComponent in it. Is
>   it in some other table?

To check where all instance of current ItemType stores

Go to HMC/BackOffice > System > Type > Search for your type and select it from result > go to `extended` tab > check for `Table` attribute value

[image]

---

> If I create a new Component or any existing, where are they stored in
>   database table?

```
<deployment table="tableName" typecode="20005" />
```

The deployment tag is used to define database table while declaring itemType. So if you define deployment tag for your custom type then it's all instances will be stored in define table otherwise it will be stored in it's parent itemtype(defined using extends attribute). By default all itemType extends GenericItem so if you don't declare extends attribute for your itemsType it will be stored in genericitems table (declared for GenericItem)

Remember

- A deployment table must be defined for all Items extending GenericItem
- A deployment table must not be defined for any Items extending any item other than GenericItem

Refer to [this wiki](https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?title=Specifying%20a%20Deployment%20for%20hybris%20Platform%20Types&spaceKey=release5) for more detail example

---

> Please any help is appreciated in understand the Hybris database
>   structure!

Refer [this](https://hybrismart.com/2018/05/06/explaining-hybris-database-structure-2/) post, explaining hybris database structure in detail

Answer (score 2):

Item table described on **deployment** element in myextension-item.xml files. If you don't describe table, your item data saved on base item table. Every item table has TypePK column for saving item type.

```
<itemtype code="MyItem" extends="GenericItem">
    <description>My item description</description>
    <deployment table="MyItem" typecode="30001" />
    <attributes>
        <attribute type="java.lang.String" qualifier="key">
            <modifiers optional="false" initial="true" />
            <persistence type="property" />
        </attribute>
        <attribute type="java.lang.String" qualifier="value">
            <persistence type="property" />
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

You can check item table in backoffice type system.

[image: type system]

Comment: this really helped me out...appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Use Flexible Search. With Flexible Search you can search for every itemtype by its name. Go to HAC / Console / Flexible Search. There are example queries and a link to the documentation